# Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

i am always getting this error when i am trying to give the UIImage parameter to my func makePost. "Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'" I tried something but nothing really worked for me, i only want to put a Image from my Assets to the func.

```
steven.makePost(image: UIImage(named: "ferrari"), appUser: steven)



func makePost(image: UIImage,appUser: User) {
    
    let post: Post = Post(ersteller: appUser, image: image, datum: "2022")
    
    feed.append(post)
    
    for i in 0..<friends.count {
        friends[i].feed.append(post)
    }
```

Comment: `UIImage(named: "ferrari")!`

Answer (score 2):

Creating an image with `UIImage(named: "ferrari")` returns type `UIImage?` because if Swift cannot find the asset with the name `ferrari`, it returns `nil`. If you wish to force the compiler to accept only `UIImage` (unwrapped), you can use `!` to force the unwrapping.

So your function call will instead be:

`steven.makePost(image: UIImage(named: "ferrari")!, appUser: steven)`

Note that using `!` is generally unsafe and should be used with caution.

Comment: Thank you mate, but where is there problem, that swift dont find the asset named "ferrari"

Comment: Basically, we know that we have an asset named "ferrari" but the Swift compiler doesn't know that. The compiler can only guarantee that the result of creating a UIImage with this asset name is either a UIImage (which is expected) or `nil`. Because in the compiler's eyes, the result might be nil, it will complain and ask us to explicitly make sure we won't be getting nil. That's why the error says we must unwrap the value from an optional type `UIImage?`, which could be nil, to a guaranteed type `UIImage` which is never nil.

Answer (score 2):

The Swift compiler takes type safety very seriously, so if a return isn't guaranteed, it will be returned as an optional. In this case, the compiler doesn't know about "ferrari", or you could use this function later with "lamborghini" and forget to add it to your assets, or you call it "Lamborghini". Either way, your app will crash.

Your better option would be to handle the optional `UIImage` in the `func` itself, like:

```
func makePost(image: UIImage?,appUser: User) {

    // The guard statement safely unwraps your optional and makes sure it
    // is not nil before using it.
    guard let image = image else { return }

    // Now it is unwrapped and safe to use.
    let post: Post = Post(ersteller: appUser, image: image, datum: "2022")
    
    feed.append(post)
    
    for i in 0..<friends.count {
        friends[i].feed.append(post)
    }
}
```

If 'image' is `nil` and not a `UIImage`, then nothing will happen, but your app won't crash.